# weekNumbersWithinDays not working in fullcalendar v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm developing a calendar view using [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/) library in ReactJS where I want to show week number in the separate column instead of the first column as shown in the image.

[image]

In the v4 docs, there was an option to show weeks in the first separate column using [weekNumbersWithinDays](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/weekNumbersWithinDays) but the option seems missing in the [v5 doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/week-number-render-hooks).

**Can somebody please suggest me a way to show week numbers in the first column.**

Here is my existing code and [codepen](https://codepen.io/jaypauberinge/pen/LYNQaZV) to demonstrate the issue:

```
<FullCalendar
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, customViewPlugin]}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    fixedWeekCount={false}
    headerToolbar={false}
    themeSystem='bootstrap'
    events={this.props.calendarEvents}
    eventContent={this.renderEventContent}
    eventDidMount={(info) => ReactTooltip.rebuild()}
    dayMaxEventRows={true}
    weekNumbers={true}
    weekNumbersWithinDays={false}      // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    weekText='Week '
    views={{
        dayGridMonth: {
            dayMaxEventRows: 3,
        },
        timeGridWeek: {
            dayMaxEventRows: 3,                
        }
    }}
    height="auto"
    ref={this.props.calendarRef} />
```

Comment: The upgrade guide (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4) says "weekNumbersWithinDays:
This is now the default behavior. The weekNumbersWithinDays:false behavior has been retired. See the old docs for an illustration of the difference." . So it's no longer possible to do what you want.

Comment: Oh man!! It was a good functionality, why they removed it? 
Anyway, is there any other workaround?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. I don't know why they removed it, you'd have to ask the maintainers of the project. maybe you should make a feature request to try and get it reinstated. https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features